# Working through the 'Getting Started' for Ruby on Rails, but hit a wall on adding validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

Decided to take up Ruby on Rails this weekend, so this morning I began to work through the [Getting Started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Everything went swimmingly until I got to section 5.10 Adding Some Validation. I updated the model and controllers accordingly, as well as the views for adding a new post, following it exactly, and ran into a non-descript error: `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

I checked the logs, which seemed to reveal an issue with the encoding of the text, so I threw:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
```

at the top of the `articles_controller.rb`, which revealed these errors:

```
undefined local variable or method ` ' for ArticlesController:Class

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:9:in `<class:ArticlesController>'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is my `articles_controller.rb` right now:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

end
```

I've followed the tutorial just as it is, and have tried redoing it a couple of times but this has me stumped since I can't figure out why its saying there's an undefined local variable. Does it have to do with defining the text encoding in the top of the `articles_controller.rb`, or is there something else I'm just missing?

**EDIT** I discovered it was indeed the spacing issues as one user mentioned, so I've now moved from one error to another haha. Thanks everyone, I'll hopefully figure this next one out.

Comment: What editor do you use? Also there is no need in `#!/bin/env ruby` only `# encoding: utf-8` or `# coding: utf-8`

Comment: I'm using Brackets, which is probably why I had to throw in the encoding comment. Its just the error with the <class:ArticlesController> and <top (required)> thats throwing me off

Comment: It's unlikely but try deleting all the whitespace around where the error is occurring and add the spaces in yourself. Sometimes when copying code from online it does weird things.

Also when you're finished with the getting started guide I highly recommend [Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all the whitespace around where the error is occurring and add the spaces in yourself.

Sometimes when copying code from online it does weird things.

(Moved comment to answer)